# Using shell command in awk not working

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following code in shell.

It does not work. So I don't know what's my mistake I was wondering if someone could help me

```
echo $i | awk -F "," '{if(NF == 1) print "Exiting..." system("exit")}'
```

so `$i` is a parameter for example `hi,hello`. And if the number of fields is equal to 1, I'd like the program to exit.

Comment: Do you want the script that contains the above code to exit? Since the awk command runs in a different process you cannot exit like this. You could however call the exit command (without system) from awk, with a specific exit code, and then check awk's exit code from the shell script.

Comment: @user000001 if NF is equal to 1, I want the WHOLE code to exit.

Comment: @ Matin Added an example for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call exit through system, because awk is executed in a separate process. However, you can call exit from awk, with a specified error code, and then exit the script depending on the error code. Example:

```
awk -F "," '{if(NF==1){ print "Exiting"; exit -1}}' || exit
```

Comment: @Matin It shouldn't exit for `NF>1`. Perhaps you did not separate the fields with comma (`,`)? Also note that you forgot a set of curly brackets in the code in your question

Comment: i do :(
I have my string is `--only:4,3,2,1` lots of commas. but it still exits

Comment: @Matin Strange... Try `echo "1,2,3 " | awk -F "," '{if(NF==1){ print NF "Exiting"; exit -1}}' || exit`. I did it on my system and it worked...

Comment: it worked
The problem was `<<< "1"` I didn't have to put that

Comment: @Matin Yes the `<<< "1"` is a different way of specifying input redirection when the input is a string (equivalent to `echo "1" | ...`) If the input comes from another command, then you should not add it.

Answer (score 3):

Awk cannot force its parent process to exit, but you can refactor the code so the calling shell exits.

In this limited context, you don't need Awk at all, though.

```
case $i in
  *,* ) ;; # nothing
  * ) echo Exiting... >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```